# How to find URL on which asp.net core docker service is running?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have developed ASP.Net core service and containerized using Docker. After that Docker image is hosted inside Amazon ECR. Now I am able to pull image from Amazon ECR using Amazon CLI Windows Powershell tool and it seems that service is also running. But my issue is how to recognize which URL I need to listen? Reference screenshot is attached below.

[image]

I above URL, message displaying "Now listening on http://[::]:80 but I have tried out below possible combinations.

1. http://localhost:80 and http://localhost:5000 https://localhost:80
   and http://localhost:5001 http://172.17.20.1:80/
   http://172.17.20.1:5000 and http://172.17.20.1:5001

P.S 172.17.20.1 is docker instance's IP with reference to below URL

https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-launch-the-net-core-website-in-docker/48129/7

Comment: Can you paste your `docker run` command. Mask the image name if you don't want it to be exposed.

Comment: Are you trying on local machine?

Comment: Hello mchawre,

I am using below command

docker run DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME MYIMAGE

Comment: Hi Sameer, Yes I am trying to execute that image from my local machine

Comment: It seems your container is running in `bridge` networking mode. So you need to map your port -p 80:80 (-p hostport:containerport). Or else run container in host mode using `--net=host` option in docker run.

Comment: Thank you mchawre for your reply but can you guide me which should be IP address? whether it should be localhost or IP of docker instance?

Comment: `localhost` or public/private ip of your machine should work.